# Prove that every sufficiently large Fourier coefficient is positive

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ and let the nth Fourier coefficient be defined as:

$$c_n = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t) e^{-int} dt$$

I just wondered wether there is any way (any sufficient, necessary or sufficient and necessary condition) to determinate wether $c_n >0$ for any sufficiently large $n$ (assuming that we had already proved that, for our function $f$, $c_n \in \mathbb{R}$). I would also be interested in trigonometric coefficients instead of exponential ones.

Reading about it, I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2102972/346773) related question, regarding the positiveness of all of the trigonometric Fourier coefficietns. I also found some interesting information about applying the saddle-point method to this situation, or even expressing $f(z)$ as the product of its modulus and the complex exponential of the argument. However, I have not been able to arrive at any conclusion.

Comment: I don't think there is any simpler condition than "$f$ must be the sum of a trigonometric polynomial and a function with positive Fourier coefficients", the latter being described by the linked post.

Comment: It may be simple to express, but it is definitively such a difficult way to check wether a given a funcion $f(z)$ satisfies that condition

Comment: I'm a little confused about your definition of $c_n$. Is this a path integral (as $dz$ suggests) or an integral on $\mathbb{T}$ (as the bounds of $-\pi$ and $\pi$ suggest)?

Comment: @Ryan Corrected notation to prevent misunderstandings