# Fitting discrete points using Fourier series with nonnegative coefficients

Tags: fourier-series

Suppose I have a set of desired points $(x_1, f(x_1)), (x_2, f(x_2)),..., (x_n, f(x_n))$, with $x_i\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x_i)\in\mathbb{C}$. I want to find a Fourier series for $f(x)$,
$$f(x)=\sum_{j=-d}^dp_je^{ijx\omega}$$
that passes through the desired points and **also satisfies $p_j\ge0$**; finite integer $d$ and nonnegative $\omega$ are free parameters. Two questions:

1. Is this always possible for sufficiently large $d$, and if not, under what conditions on the points is it impossible?
2. What $d$ is required, as a function of $n$?

Note: there are many related questions on StackExchange about conditions on a *whole function* for its Fourier series or transform to be nonnegative, e.g., [Fourier series with non-negative coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2102972/fourier-series-with-non-negative-coefficients), but I have not found any that address the weaker requirement of fitting a discrete set of points.